# Searchbar "filter" badge

Tags: ios, swift, search

a spent a lot of time with searching this feature. I would like to add this to my app, but I don't know how.
Has anyone any idea what is this please?

I need to add 2018 badge etc to my searchbar.

[image]

Thank you for help

Comment: Did you try adding `leftView` property in your `UISearchBar`?

Comment: nope, thank you for tip - ill try it

Comment: These are usually called tokens and sadly, there isn't a native UI component for them in iOS. Try a search for creating token fields in iOS, there are lots of great libraries for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at UISearchToken available for iOS 13.0+: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchtoken

Apple provides a great tutorial to help you get started with these components: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/using_suggested_searches_with_a_search_controller